# Использовать в кнопке 2 переменную созданную в кнопке 1

Tags: c#

Kак сделать доступной переменную?

Пишу так:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] str = new string[textBox1.Lines.Length];
    str[0] = textBox1.Lines[0];                         // Первая прочитанная строка 
    char[] word = new char[str[0].Length];              //  получаем массив в котором будут все символы выбранной строки

    for (int i = 0; i < str[0].Length; i++) 
    {
        word[i] = str[0][i];
    }
    int [] ASKI = new int [word.Length];                // Массив с АСКИ кодами
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        ASKI[i] = word[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Convert.ToString(ASKI[i]);
    }
}

public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

    char[] decod = new char[ASKI.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        decod[i] = Convert.ToChar(ASKI[i]);
    }
    textBox1.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < decod.Length; i++)
    {
        textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + Convert.ToString(decod[i]);
    }
}
```

Не дает обращаться к массиву ASKI во второй кнопке. Код при работе на одной кнопке работает.

Comment: А с чего должно «давать» обращаться к `ASKI`? Он не существует в контексте указанной Вами функции. Сделайте тогда переменную глобальной и дело с концом

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сделайте вот так:

```
private int [] ASKI = null;

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] str = new string[textBox1.Lines.Length];
    str[0] = textBox1.Lines[0];                         // Первая прочитанная строка 
    char[] word = new char[str[0].Length];              //  получаем массив в котором будут все символы выбранной строки

    for (int i = 0; i < str[0].Length; i++) 
    {
        word[i] = str[0][i];
    }
    ASKI = new int [word.Length];                // Массив с АСКИ кодами
    // etc
}

public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (ASKI != null)
    {
        char[] decod = new char[ASKI.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            decod[i] = Convert.ToChar(ASKI[i]);
        }
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все сработало

Answer (score 1):

Вместо переменной используй поле класса.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте

```
private Int32[] ASKI = null;
```